# How many squares can be made from points on $ z(t) = e^{2\pi i\, t} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} e^{2\pi i\, 3t} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, geometric-probability

Inspire by the Toeplitz Square Problem, how many squares can be drawn on the curve:
$$ z(t) = e^{2\pi i\, t} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} e^{2\pi i\, 3t} $$
wth $t \in [0, 2\pi]$.  Here is an image:

[image]

We're up to  <del>one</del> <del>five</del> <del>nine</del> **ten** squares.  Here is an example that is not aligned wit the axes. <del>can be prove there only one square here?</del>  It's not quite square, can we move it around to be a square?

E.g. Can this quadrilateral be massaged into a square?  Whose points all lie on this cubic curve?

---

i heard the existence of **one** square is known for algebraic curves like this. maybe with no guarantee of exact count. a dimension count has that a quadrilateral is defined by 8 real numbers. the squares in Euclidean plane can be defined by 4 numbers. the quadrilaterals on a curve are defines by 4 numbers. generically  these curves should intersect in a $$4+4-8=0$$ dimensional set. possibly an empty collection of points.

Other possible obstructions is when these curves are very bumpy. Then I think one introduces really tiny squares!

Comment: You should probably explain a bit more what you have in mind because the way I see it, you could do at least two.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I am up to **three** I can draw approximtely where they are.  The exact computation might be some effort.

Comment: @CameronWilliams There must be at least three squares, the progress on the inscribed square problem shows that any closed peicewise analytic curve will have an inscribed square, there are three closed curves in the image. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem

Comment: There are at least $9$ axis aligned square.

Comment: Yes, you can make that into a square. Numerically, the square you have looks like the one having vertices at
$$
( 1.191840337616712,0.8762580923680066),\\
(-0.1554901579762806,0.5869927399759873),\\
(0.1337751944157387,-0.7603377556170049),\\
(1.481105690008731,-0.4710724032249856)
$$
You can verify they satisfy
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(x^2-y^2) - (x^2+y^2)^3 + 2(x^2+y^2)^2 + \frac{4}{27} = 0$$
which is the equation for the hextic curve given by your parametrization.

Answer (score 6):

**Summary** - There are $13$ squares inside the curve and $9$ of them are axis-aligned.

---

**Part I** - how to locate the axis-aligned squares.

Following is a picture showing $5$ of the axis-aligned ones.

[image: 5 squares inside a curve]

To locate the axis-aligned squares, we first define two auxillary functions for $t \in [0,2\pi]$.
$$\begin{cases}
X(t) &= \cos(t) + \frac{\cos(3t)}{\sqrt{3}}\\
Y(t) &= \sin(t) + \frac{\sin(3t)}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{cases}$$
In terms of $X(t), Y(t)$, the original curve (in blue) is given by the parametrization
$$[0,2\pi] \ni t \mapsto \gamma(t) = X(t) + iY(t) \in \mathbb{C}$$
Next, we define two auxillary curves
$$
[0,2\pi] \ni t \mapsto
\begin{cases}
\gamma_1(t) = (X(t)+2Y(t)) + Y(t)i & \text{( light red )}\\
\gamma_2(t) = X(t) + (Y(t)+2X(t))i & \text{( light blue )}
\end{cases} \in \mathbb{C}
$$

In order for a pair of points $z_{\pm} = x \pm iy$ to form a vertical edge of a square, one of the two pairs $z_{\pm} - 2y$ or $z_{\pm} + 2y$ need to lie on $\gamma$. Let's say $z_{\pm} - 2y$ lies on $\gamma$, then $z_+$ lies on the slanted curve $\gamma_1$ (the light red one). We can locate axis-aligned squares centered on real axis by intersecting $\gamma$ with $\gamma_1$.
By a similar argument, we can locate axis-aligned squares centered on imaginary axis by intersecting $\gamma$ with $\gamma_2$.

In first quadrant ($\Re z, \Im z > 0$) $\gamma$ and $\gamma_1$ intersect at three points. They are the points $A,B,C$ in above diagram. $\gamma$ and $\gamma_2$ also
intersect in first quadrant  in three points. One of them is $C$ and the other
two are the points $D,E$ in above diagram.

From these $5$ points, one can construct $5$ squares whose vertices lies completely
on $\gamma$. If you reflect the $4$ squares containing $A, B, D, E$ as vertices
with respect to origin, one get $4$ more squares. This means there are $9$ axis aligned squares whose vertices lie on $\gamma$.

It turns out this exhausts all axis-aligned squares.

---

**Part II** - how to count the number of squares.

To count the total number of squares, we treat $p, q$ as two variables from $[0, 2\pi]$. For each $p,q$, consider the square $PUQV$ with vertices
$$\begin{array}{rl}
P = \gamma(p),& U = \frac{1+i}{2}\gamma(p) + \frac{1-i}{2}\gamma(q)\\
Q = \gamma(q),& V = \frac{1-i}{2}\gamma(p) + \frac{1+i}{2}\gamma(q)
\end{array}
$$
As functions of $(p,q)$, $P(p,q)$ and $Q(p,q)$ always lie on $\gamma$. 
If we can figure out the two loci in $pq$-plane for $U(p,q)$ lies on $\gamma$
and for $V(p,q)$ lies on $\gamma$, the intersection of these loci will be
the parameters $(p,q)$ one need to construct a square all of its vertices lie on
$\gamma$.

To achieve this, we need a simple criterion to tell whether a point $z = x+iy$ lies on $\gamma$ or not
(or at the least, a way to filter out most points that doesn't lie on $\gamma$).  It turns out there is one:

Let $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, points on $\gamma$ are given by the parametrization:

$$z = x + iy = e^{it}(1 + a e^{2it})$$
Taking absolute value and square, we get
$$z\bar{z} = 1 + 2a\cos 2t + a^2$$
Taking real part and square, we get
$$\begin{align}a(z + \bar{z})^2 
&= 4a(\cos t + a\cos 3t)^2 = 4a\cos\theta^2(1 + a(4\cos^2 t - 3))^2\\
&= (2a + 2a\cos 2t) ( 1 - a + 2a\cos 2t)^2\\
&= (z\bar{z} - (1-a)^2)(z\bar{z} - a(a+1))^2
\end{align}
$$
Substitute $a$ back by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and simplify, we get
$$\Lambda(z) \stackrel{def}{=} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(z^2+\bar{z}^2) - (z\bar{z})^3 + 2(z\bar{z})^2 + \frac{4}{27}
= 0$$
This means $\gamma$ is contained inside the hexic curve

$$\Lambda(x+iy) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(x^2 - y^2) - (x^2+y^2)^3 + 2(x^2+y^2)^2 + \frac{4}{27} = 0$$

In principle, we can locate the desired parameters by
finding the two loci in $(p,q) \in [0,2\pi]$ for
$$\Lambda(U(p,q)) = \Lambda\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\gamma(p) + \frac{1-i}{2}\gamma(q)\right) = 0\\
\Lambda(V(p,q)) = \Lambda\left(\frac{1-i}{2}\gamma(p) + \frac{1+i}{2}\gamma(q)\right) = 0
$$
and compute their intersections. Excluding those with $p = q$, these are the parameters for constructing the squares we seek.

---

**Part III** - the result.

To understand what the two loci look like, I wrote a program to compute $\Lambda(U(p,q))$ and $\Lambda(V(p,q))$ as some sort of heatmap. This is the heatmap I get:

[image: A heatmap of Lambdas]

Above heatmap cover the parameter space for $(p,q) \in [0,2\pi]^2$.

- A point is red  when $\Lambda(U(p,q))$ is close to zero.
- A point is blue when $\Lambda(V(p,q))$ is close to zero.

Outside the diagonal $p = q$, the red and blue "strips" intersect at $56$ points.
Four of them, e.g. the point labelled by $X$, comes from the two self intersection points of $\gamma$, they don't give us any squares.

The remaining $52$ intersections falls into $\frac{52}{4} = 13$ groups.
Each group give us one square. For each group, I have picked one of the
member and label them:

- Squares $A, B, C, D, E$ contain a vertex with same name in first figure.
- Squares $A', B', D' E'$ are images of square $A, B, C, D$ under $z \to -z$.
- Square $Y$ is the non-axis aligned square with vertices at:
  $$\begin{array}{lr}
  (+1.191840337616712,  &+0.8762580923680066),\\
  (-0.1554901579762806, &+0.5869927399759873),\\ 
  (+0.1337751944157387, &-0.7603377556170049),\\
  (+1.481105690008731,  &-0.4710724032249856)
  \end{array}$$
- Squares $Y', Z, Z'$ are the image of square $Y$ under $z \to -z$, $z \to \bar{z}$ and $z \to -\bar{z}$ respectively.

In short, if I didn't make any mistake in analyzing above heatmap, there are $13$ squares formed from points on $\gamma$. $9$ of them is axis-aligned while the remaining $4$ non-axis aligned.

Comment: what's with the faint slanted curves? looks awesone!

Comment: @cactus314 they are the curves $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$ in answer. let's say you want a pair of points $(x,\pm y)$ to form a vertical edge of a square, then one of the two pairs $(x-2y,\pm y)$ or $(x+2y,\pm y)$ need to lie on $\gamma$. Let's say $(x-2y,\pm y)$ lies on $\gamma$, then $(x,y)$ lies on the slanted curve $\gamma_1$ (the light red one).

Comment: this is truly phenomenal. i would give *two* up-votes if I could. would you share your `code` (e.g.  Mathematica/Python/Julia/Fortran ) and how you derived that 6-degree curve in your comments ?

Comment: @cactus314 The code I have is in maxima but it crashes when generate some implicit plots which I believe can identify all possible squares. The example I show you has been obtained by some adhoc root finding. I'll outline what I have done and how to derive the curve tomorrow.